# Using menus to link to sections on the home page

Tags: menus, homepage

I have many menu items linking to sections (anchors) on pages. They are working fine on every page except the home page. ON the home page, the first time you click on a menu item it works, but the 2nd time, it goes to a different page.

See about.tap2open.com.  Under home, you'll see residents, visitors, and communities. If you click on any one, it works. But if you click again, it goes to a different page on the site.

I'm guessing it has to do with the homepage being about.tap2Open.com without a page name. The homepage is simply called about.tap2open.com. I'm wondering if I rename the page if that would fix it. I'm afraid of breaking something else though!

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you named your homepage the same as your url?  Don't do that.

I'm more curious about what code you put in your menus to attach the anchors though.  You should have separate menus for pages if you are doing anchors on them. Your link should be `#anchor`. This way the page doesn't reload when you click it.

If you want to link from another page to your homepage anchor it should be `/#anchor`  **NOT** `https://about.tap2open.com/#anchor` so you don't have to do any restructuring later.